# How to use interfaces with Telerik OpenAccess

Tags: telerik, openaccess

I am trying to implement my persitent classes using interfaces. I have created the following

```
public interface IFoo
{
    int Id {get;set;}
}

public class Foo : IFoo
{
    private int _id;

    public int Id {get{return _id;} set{_id = value;}}
}

public interface IBar
{
    int Id {get;set;}
    IFoo Foo {get;set;}
}

public class Bar : IBar
{
    private int _id;
    private IFoo _foo;

    public int Id {get{return _id;} set{_id = value;}}
    public IFoo Foo {get{return _foo;} set{_foo = value;}}
}
```

Is it possible to indicate that Foo is a valid class and to use it by default, i dont want to use the database to store the class type.

Thanks

Rohan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after reading through the Telerik guide i posted a question on their forum...

[Using Interfaces without storing the Class Type in the database](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/orm/general-discussions/using-interfaces.aspx)

It looks like its not possible.

Answer (score 2):

The descriminator column is always necessary because OpenAccess does not know if there might be more valid implementations later. What you can do is to use a direct Foo reference as private field and expose it as Interface property. The class cast exception in the setter might help you to find the places where a wrong object is set.

Hope that helps,

Jan

Answer (score 1):

Check out these links:

http://www.telerik.com/help/openaccess-orm/classes-persistent-interfaces.html

http://www.telerik.com/help/openaccess-orm/the-.net-data-model-user-defined-interfaces.html